# Plot points scatter distant enough and link them

Tags: python

If I have a function T[i][j] = [k,l] i would like to plot a 2D figure with the point (i,j), the point (k,l) and a line between them as we can see here :

[image: Idea]

The problem of this picture is that the blue and the red points are distant enough which won't be the case for exemple image that T[i][j] = [i, j+1] it's going to be a mess. 
We need 4 axis 2 for the bleu and two for the red, but I think it might be too difficult to have a nice picture like this.
My idea is then axe off, not to plot them, and to separate the point [i,j] from [k,l] by adding a number C to [k,l], [k,l] + C, large enough in order to separate [i,j] from [k,l] + C enough. I think C = 4*max (i-k)**2 + (j-l)**2 should work.

I'm looking for your help to help me to code it in python if you want. I have some basis but it won't be enough for sur ^^.
And if you have any idea to improve mine, I'll be happy to hear it. 
One last thing, it might be great to be able to plot point instead of cross and add weight to the point. For exemple the size of the point [i,j] will be determining according to M[i][j] a matrix which give the mass the point.

Thanks and regards.

Comment: Why not just plot a few select blue connecting lines?

Comment: Yes indeed, what's the difference ?